# При просмотре проверки из истории не показывается, какое сообщение проверялось

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/518929

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Сколько я проверяю, никогда и не показывалось...

Comment: @VictorVosMottor похоже, это только для вопросов, по которым выбрано "Закрыть". Оформил [багу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354364/339911) на MSE.